# Table show/hide columns

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a typical table,

7 columns, (paginated to 100 rows per time).

What I want to do is have a `<select multiple="multiple">` and have it list all the columns based off the name is the respective `<th></th>`, I then want to hook into the select onchange event, when a change occurs hide all columns that are **not** selected, for each column hidden decrease the colspan of the `<tfoot>` by 1.

The table structure is:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>
    <th>second</th>
    <th>third</th>
    <th>fourth</th>
    <th>fifth</th>
    <th>sixth</th>
    <th>seventh</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="7"></td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

and I suspect the ending select will look like:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1" selected="selected">first</option>
 <option value="2" selected="selected">second</option>
 <option value="3" selected="selected">third</option>
 <option value="4" selected="selected">fourth</option>
 <option value="5" selected="selected">fifth</option>
 <option value="6" selected="selected">sixth</option>
 <option value="7" selected="selected">seventh</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455699/show-hide-table-column-with-colspan-using-jquery for answer with colspan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example: [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/FD9dp/12/)

And here's a summary of the code on how to do it:

```
<table class="editable_table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>
    <th>second</th>
    <th>third</th>
    <th>fourth</th>
    <th>fifth</th>
    <th>sixth</th>
    <th>seventh</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>7</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <td class="footer" colspan="7">This is the footer</td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
<select multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1" selected="selected">first</option>
 <option value="2" selected="selected">second</option>
 <option value="3" selected="selected">third</option>
 <option value="4" selected="selected">fourth</option>
 <option value="5" selected="selected">fifth</option>
 <option value="6" selected="selected">sixth</option>
 <option value="7" selected="selected">seventh</option>
</select>
```

And the javascript:

```
function hideCol($table, myIndex){
    $table.find("tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("th:eq("+myIndex+"), td:eq("+myIndex+")").not('.footer').hide();
    });
}

function showCol($table, myIndex){
    $table.find("tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("th:eq("+myIndex+"), td:eq("+myIndex+")").not('.footer').show();
    });
}

$("select").change(function(){
    var $table = $(".editable_table"),
        cols = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 1; i <= $table.find("th").length; i++){
        if (cols.indexOf(i+'') === -1) {
            hideCol($table, i-1);
        } else {
            showCol($table, i-1);
        }
    }
    $table.find("tfoot td").attr('colspan', cols.length);
});
```

Since your question was rather vague, I assume this is what you wanted. In any case, it should do the trick!

PS - might not be the most efficient way of doing it - but consider improving the efficiency an *exercise for the reader*, as they say.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/96G7N/

Take care of edge conditions (e.g. unselecting all options)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".table-column-selector").change(function(){
        var selectedCols = $(this).val();
        var cols = $("table.tableClass thead th").length;

        var footer = $("table.tableClass tfoot tr td");

        footer.attr("colspan", selectedCols.length);

        for (col = cols - 1 ; col >= 0 ; col--) {
            var columns = $("table.tableClass tbody tr td:nth-child(" + (col + 1) + ")");
            var headers = $("table.tableClass thead tr th:nth-child(" + (col + 1) + ")");

            if ($.inArray( col + 1 + "", selectedCols ) != -1) {
               columns.show();
               headers.show();
            }
            else {
                columns.hide();
                headers.hide();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do this, http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/mFmjb/2/

jQuery:

```
// setup re-usable variables
var $myGrid = $('#myGrid'),
    $colFilter = $('#columnFilter'),
    optionElementTemplate = "<option value=\"{0}\">{0}</option>";    

// iterate the <th> tags to build the multi-select box
$('th', $myGrid).each(function() {
    // create a jquery object to append from the optionElementTemplate and the <th> text
    $colFilter.append($(optionElementTemplate.replace(/\{0\}/g, $(this).text())));
});

$colFilter.change(function() {
    // store count for footer
    var count = 0;

    // show all columns
    resetTable();

    // iterate over the select options for selected values
    $('option', this).each(function() {
        if(!$(this).attr("selected")) {
            count++;
            hideColumn($(this).index());
        }
    });

    // adjust the colspan
    adjustFooter($('option', this).length - count);
});

function resetTable() {
    $('#myGrid td, #myGrid th').show();
    $('#myGrid tfoot td').attr("colspan", $('#columnFilter option').length);
}

function hideColumn(index) {
    $('#myGrid thead th:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
    $('#myGrid tbody td:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
}

function adjustFooter(count) {
    $('#myGrid tfoot td').attr("colspan", count);
}
```

Probably some fine tuning before putting this in production, but the functionality is there.